# School, fiqh, sect?

Tags: discussion, sect

When posting a fatwa to answer a question, is it important to mention the school of though, fiqh, sect etc from this the fatwa is from?

I've noticed people asking for such details and I have noticed many posts from all sorts of schools, fiqhs, sects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the OP might want to know the opinions of multiple sects/fiqhs. So it really depends on the person asking and his intention. If they don't specify a certain school of thought, then it should be assumed that a multiple opinion answer is acceptable unless proven otherwise.